# Fill JComboBox when selecting Department Name

Tags: java, database

```
try{
    String sql = "Select First_Name,MI,Last_Name from User_Table\n" +
                 "inner join Department_Table on User_Table.Department_ID=Department_Table.Department_ID\n" +
                 "where Department_Name = ? ";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    pst.setString(1, (String)DoctorDep.getSelectedItem());
    String add1 = rs.getString("First_Name");
    String add2 = rs.getString("MI");
    String add3 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
    DoctorNames.addItem(add1+" "+add2+" "+add3);
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}finally {
   try {
       rs.close();
       pst.close();
   }catch(Exception e){
   }
}
```

I select Department Name on `JComboBox` Department Name and it will select the name of the doctor listed on that department but it shown the error message result-set closed and it is not filling the combo box Doctor Name. Is there a mistake or it is not possible to do?

Comment: You should call `pst.setString` BEFORE `pst.executeQuery`, otherwise you've not bound any values to the query.  Also, you should be calling `rs.next()` before attempting to access the results (and test the result of `rs.next`) - this is all pretty basic functionality.  I think you need to go back to basics starting with the [JDBC Basics trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: Sir thank you for your respond this could help me sir im a Grade 12 student just a beginner in programming and I starting to learn more about java language sir thank you again

Comment: Best of luck to you on your journey.  But remember, SO is not a replacement for self-learning or investigation. JDBC is a very common topic with no end of available resources. One of the marks of a good developer is the ability to research and investigate issues, 90% of my job is spent trying to better understand why something isn't working and how I might make it work. Experience is more about what the most appropriate approach might be to solve a problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

- You should call `pst.setString` BEFORE `pst.executeQuery`, otherwise you've not bound the values to the query
- You should call `rs.next` (and check it's return value) BEFORE attempting to access the values the result, otherwise you'll be "before the first" result.
- You should also be using `e.printStackTrace()` as it will provide you will additional information about the exception (you really should be logging it, but lets start there)
- You should be using the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to better manage your resources, as you're running the risk of leaving some of them open

I would suggest that you take the time to go through the [JDBC Basics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) as these aren't so much a program or API issues as a misunderstanding of how to the API